# How to convert Java Object to JSON string?

Tags: java, javascript, json, model-view-controller

Hello i'm trying to convert my Java Object to a Json string to use in my view with javascript functions.

I tried to use Google's gson lib:

```
String myjson = "";
Gson gson = new Gson();
myjson = gson.toJson(myuser);//myuser is my java object
```

However when i call myjson, it consists of '`&quot;`' instead of the character '`"`' for this reason i can't able to use it in my view, it is creating me problems.

How can I fix this, how can I create Json string properly?

Edit : Is there a chance of making a mistake while rendering the myjson?

Edit2: To reach the result of myjson in view, i'm doing

> render(myjson);

at the end of my code.

Edit3: Play framework has a method of renderJSON(). However i can't use it since i'm rendering not only myjson and some other elements too.

Comment: So if you do `System.out.println(myjson);` right after `myjson = gson.toJson(myuser);`, you see `&quot;` instead of `"`?

Comment: You must HTML-escape the JSON string somehow. What are you doing with the JSON string?

Comment: actually, it is not in java totally. I'm using mvc, so this code is from my controller, and when i call myjson in my view, it is giving me myjson with quot;

Comment: Which mvc? Is it spring? or what?

Comment: i'm using play framework

Comment: If you are using Play Framework, try adding this to your HTML/JS code, @{Html(new Gson().toJson(yourObjectToSerialize))};. This worked for me, as I ran into a similar issue.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Note that "&quot" is "Proper" JSON, so your javascript can be escaped properly, anyways if you dont want to use entities in you JSON perhaps you want to disable html formatting/escaping.

Try using

```
Gson gson = new GsonBuilder().disableHtmlEscaping().create();
```

Check the GSONBuilder Object Documentation http://google-gson.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/gson/docs/javadocs/com/google/gson/GsonBuilder.html

Answer (score 0):

I think he's protecting you against html special chars.

Try something like that:

```
Gson gson = new Gson();
String target = "my text";
String json = gson.toJson(target);
```

This code is extract from http://google-gson.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/gson/docs/javadocs/com/google/gson/Gson.html (the api).