# Gson generate json with &quot;,js throw error

Tags: javascript, java, json, gson

i use Gson to create string like:
new Gson.toJson(englishResult); englishResult is List> type.
but the result is like:

```
[{&quot;name&quot;:&quot;en3&quot;,&quot;value&quot;:234},{&quot;name&quot;:&quot;en4&quot;,&quot;value&quot;:135},{&quot;name&quot;:&quot;en1&quot;,&quot;value&quot;:335},{&quot;name&quot;:&quot;en2&quot;,&quot;value&quot;:310},{&quot;name&quot;:&quot;en5&quot;,&quot;value&quot;:1548}]
```

and then i invoke js method throw error

> Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token &

i search goole,it tells me &quot is good json,because i can contain escape,but why js throws error? how to solve it?
plz tell me some suggestion,thanks very much

my server code is :

```
 public static void pieTestWithData(){

        Map<String, Integer> result = getChineseResultMap();
        List<Map<String, Object>> englishResult = getFormatteredPieData();
        renderArgs.put("resultData", getJson(englishResult));
        render();
    }

 private static String getJson(List<Map<String, Object>> englishResult) {
        Gson gson = new GsonBuilder()
                .disableHtmlEscaping()
                .create();
        return gson.toJson(englishResult);
    }
```

Comment: can you paste full json data?

Comment: Yeah, paste an example o the JSON that has gone wrong.

Comment: maybe a simlar issue [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8541040/how-to-convert-java-object-to-json-string). A question: are your sure to not convert your List (englishResult) into String before calling toJson(...) ? You need to pass List object directly

Answer (score 0, accepted):

*(Posted here because stackoverflow comments are limited to 264 characters)*

@wangyiran

I was unable to reproduce. Here is my test:

```
public class Toto {
    private String name;
    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }
    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }
}
```

then

```
    @Test
    public void testMe() {
        List<Map<String, Object>> englishResult = new ArrayList<>();
        Toto toto = new Toto();
        toto.setName("Toto it's me");
        Map<String, Object> m = new HashMap<String, Object>();
        m.put("mapKey", toto);
        englishResult.add(m);

        Gson gson = new Gson();
        String jsonEnglishResult = gson.toJson(englishResult);
        System.out.println(jsonEnglishResult);
    }
```

Test output:

```
[{"mapKey":{"name":"Toto it\u0027s me"}}]
```

I'm using Gson version `2.3.1`.